# Remote neo4j connection Permission denied error

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

i can reach neo4j server from localhost and run queries successfully but i can't run query from remote computer. On remote computer i can access neo4j from browser. http://x.x.x.x:7474 drives me to neo4j web interface. But when i execute a query from spring it gives permision denied error.Query is simple:

```
User u = new User();
u.setName("test");
session.save(u);
```

ogm.properties:

```
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver
URI=http://neo4j:1234@x.x.x.x:7474
```

full stack trace is:

```
2016-04-25 17:37:31.531  INFO 6040 --- [tp2116224318-27] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread 27: request {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`User`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as nodeRef, ID(n) as nodeId","parameters":{"rows":[{"nodeRef":-83203329,"props":{"name":"test"}}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
2016-04-25 17:37:31.531  INFO 6040 --- [tp2116224318-27] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread 27: POST http://neo4j:1234@x.x.x.x:7474/db/data/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1
2016-04-25 17:37:31.533  INFO 6040 --- [tp2116224318-27] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://x.x.x.x:7474: Permission denied: connect
2016-04-25 17:37:31.534  INFO 6040 --- [tp2116224318-27] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->http://x.x.x.x:7474
2016-04-25 17:37:31.535  INFO 6040 --- [tp2116224318-27] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://x.x.x.x:7474: Permission denied: connect
2016-04-25 17:37:31.535  INFO 6040 --- [tp2116224318-27] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->http://x.x.x.x:7474
2016-04-25 17:37:31.537  INFO 6040 --- [tp2116224318-27] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://x.x.x.x:7474: Permission denied: connect
2016-04-25 17:37:31.537  INFO 6040 --- [tp2116224318-27] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->http://x.x.x.x:7474
2016-04-25 17:37:31.538  WARN 6040 --- [tp2116224318-27] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread 27: Caught IOException : Permission denied: connect
2016-04-25 17:37:31.543  WARN 6040 --- [tp2116224318-27] o.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler   : 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ResultProcessingException: Could not obtain new Transaction: 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:980) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224) ~[websocket-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ResultProcessingException: Could not obtain new Transaction: 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver.newTransactionUrl(HttpDriver.java:138) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver.newTransaction(HttpDriver.java:87) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.openTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:57) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate.beginTransaction(TransactionsDelegate.java:37) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.beginTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:380) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor.executeSave(RequestExecutor.java:68) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:70) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:43) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:364) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.rest.controller.HomeController.index(HomeController.java:56) ~[bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ResultProcessingException: Failed to execute request: 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver.executeHttpRequest(HttpDriver.java:119) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver.newTransactionUrl(HttpDriver.java:133) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ConnectionException: Error connecting to remote graph over HTTP
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:261) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver.executeHttpRequest(HttpDriver.java:94) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:227) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

neo4j-server.properties

```
#***************************************************************
# Server configuration
#***************************************************************

# Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j
dbms.security.auth_enabled=true
dbms.security.allow_outgoing_browser_connections=true
#
# HTTP Connector
#

# http port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474

# Let the webserver only listen on the specified IP. Default is localhost (only
# accept local connections). Uncomment to allow any connection. Please see the
# security section in the neo4j manual before modifying this.
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0

#
# HTTPS Connector
#

# Turn https-support on/off
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true

# https port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7473

# Certificate location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
#dbms.security.tls_certificate_file=conf/ssl/snakeoil.cert

# Private key location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
#dbms.security.tls_key_file=conf/ssl/snakeoil.key

# Internally generated keystore (don't try to put your own
# keystore there, it will get deleted when the server starts)
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.keystore.location=data/keystore

#*****************************************************************
# Administration client configuration
#*****************************************************************


# Comma separated list of JAX-RS packages containing JAX-RS resources, one
# package name for each mountpoint. The listed package names will be loaded
# under the mountpoints specified. Uncomment this line to mount the
# org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged.HelloWorldResource.java from
# neo4j-examples under /examples/unmanaged, resulting in a final URL of
# http://localhost:${org.neo4j.webserver.port}/examples/unmanaged/helloworld/{nodeId}
#org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged

#*****************************************************************
# HTTP logging configuration
#*****************************************************************

# HTTP logging is disabled. HTTP logging can be enabled by setting this
# property to 'true'.
org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=true

# Logging policy file that governs how HTTP log output is presented and
# archived. Note: changing the rollover and retention policy is sensible, but
# changing the output format is less so, since it is configured to use the
# ubiquitous common log format
org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=D:/neo4jdata/neo4j-http-logging.xml
dbms.querylog.filename=D:/neo4jdata/queries.log
```

Comment: have you uncommented `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0` in neo4j-server.properties?

Comment: added properties as answer

Comment: Do not post additional info as an answer. Edit your question.

Comment: I edited the question do you have any idea what the problem is ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a 'neo4j' issue. This looks more like firewall related exception because a `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect` which probably means there is a firewall blocking your request for port 7474. Yes I know you can connect fine from your browser but neo4j/apache HttpClient are opening java.net sockets internally and it is being blocked. Other users have had similar issues with java.net sockets depending on firewall settings, java version used, OS version, etc...

Try to open a direct connection using java.net socket to http://x.x.x.x:7474 or using Apache HttpClient and see if you still get the same exception. That should tell you whether or not spring data neo4j lib is the cause.

See these question/answers to trouble shoot further:

[Random UnreachableBrowserException when running Selenium tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549475/random-unreachablebrowserexception-when-running-selenium-tests)

Also see:

http://jonathangiles.net/blog/?p=1126